# YADCF range_slider not showing up after beta-21 release

Tags: datatables, yadcf

After updating **yadcf** from beta-19 to beta-21 and beta-24 the range_number_slider is not rendered properly anymore. Am I missing something new?

Version beta-19 working
http://live.datatables.net/yuqumamo/3/edit?html,js,output

Version beta-21 not working
http://live.datatables.net/yuqumamo/4/edit?html,js,output

Version beta-24 doesn't fix the issue either.
http://live.datatables.net/yuqumamo/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out, I just released a 0.9.4-beta.25 which fixes it

p.s

when its clearly a bug feel free to open an issue in github repo

Comment: Okey ! I wasn't sure if it was my fault by missing something. Thanks for your great support !